# mysql pandas unicode error while querying on columns

Tags: python, mysql, unicode

I have a csv file which Im reading via pandas.Then Im trying to call a mysql query on that file which is throwing up error.

```
import pandas
import pandasql
fl=pandas.read_csv('file.csv')
```

Columns of the file are

```
fl.columns
Index([ u'time', u'contact', u'address'], dtype='object')
```

The query is

```
q=u"""
SELECT contact FROM fl LIMIT 50
"""
```

WHich im running as

```
fl_solution=pandasql.sqldf(q,locals())
```

The error Im getting is :-

```
ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried using a different encoding as per suggestion by harshad.

encoding = "ISO-8859-1" , and thereafter the mysql queries are working fine too.

Comment: you should likely have accepted @harshad 's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this:

`fl=pandas.read_csv('file.csv',encoding='utf-8')`

It specifies to encode file into `utf-8` encoding. Also try to encode the strings into `utf-8` wherever you are using strings fetched from either file or external source.

For e.g.:

`stringname.encode('utf-8')`

Comment: fl=pandas.read_csv('file.csv',encoding='utf-8')  ____ ERROR :::::::
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 596: invalid start byte

Comment: Then I guess your file is in another encoding. Try to find out file encoding & put it while opening file.

Comment: encoding = "ISO-8859-1" worked for me. But still column names are appended with silly u. Its been a very frustrating day, wasting it entirely on this u

Comment: `u` appended to the string shows that string encoding is unicode (you probably might know that). You have 'latin-1' encoding for your file. [This](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) documentation might help you in further reading.

Comment: BTW are you using any editor or interpreter? See encoding of that. Might be because of that it's reading columns in unicode. Try to change the settings.